# Sumar 2 campos en Reporte RDL, reporting services

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, rdlc

quiero sumar 2 campos pero no cual seria la consulta realizando un reporte RDL

tengo estos 2 campos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de los cuales en mi diseño quiero sumarlos, ya que los 2 entregan un numero entero

sin embargo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba intentando acá sumarlos pero se como

Alguien que me ayude porfa?

Comment: Hola Marco, podrías decir si la respuesta dada te fue útil, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
=First(Fields!Campo1.Value, "DataSet1") + First(Fields!Campo2.Value, "DataSet1")
```

De esta forma sumas los valores de ambos campos, es decir obtienes el valor del campo1 y del campo2 y los sumas, esta suma la mostrarías por ejemplo en un **TextBox** o en determinada columna de un **Tablix**.

Comment: Te comento que intente realizar esto, si me suma solo que tengo un detalle, a eso quiero añadirle una condicionante en la cual me sume siempre y cuando otro campo sea igual a algo, como podria hacerlo?

Comment: @MarcoTulio pero eso no lo habias dicho, yo respondi lo q preguntabas, edita tu pregunta y aclara bien lo q quieres